# What does: "Can't modify shard key's value fieldid for collection: foo.foo" mean in MongoDB-Perl?

Tags: perl, mongodb

I have the foo.foo collection sharded like this:

```
db.runCommand( { shardcollection: "foo.foo", key: { id: 1 } } );
```

When I do an upsert of some document:

```
$connection->update(
    { id => 42 },
    { '$set' => { id => 42 } },   # using the '$set' modifier
    { upsert => 1, safe => 1 },
);
```

I get this exception:

```
Can't modify shard key's value fieldid for collection: foo.foo
```

If I do an upsert without modifiers:

```
$result = $collection->update(
    { id => $args{doc_id} },
    { id => 42 },                 # regular upsert without modifier
    { upsert => 1, safe => 1 },
);
```

I get this error:

```
cannot modify shard key for collection: foo.foo
```

But when I shard like this instead:

```
# 'id' has been changed to '_id'
db.runCommand( { shardcollection: "foo.foo", key: { _id: 1 } } );
```

Then when I do the same upsert as above, I get this exception:

```
can't upsert something without shard key
```

What is a `"shard key's value fieldid"`?

**Why can I not do an upsert that sets the "id" with or without modifiers as shown in the first 2 examples?**

In either case, inserts work fine. It's upserts that throw exceptions.

Answer (score 12):

Two things :

1. Shard keys are immutable. Once you set them they cannot be updated. This makes sense because it would result in data having to be moved from one shard to another. So, update that include fields that are (or are part of) the shard key will fail with the error you're getting. The first two error messages are both the same error.
2. You cannot make inserts into a sharded collection without the shard key. Again, this makes sense from mongo's point of view. If you're not providing a shard key how will it know to which shard it should route the insert? An upsert operation should therefore include the shard key in the find "criteria" (so, the first parameter in `update(criteria, update, upsert, multi)`) but not the "update" since that's the only correct way to get the shard key in an upserted document without having it in the "update" parameter which, as you noticed, is not allowed.

Make sense?

Comment: I get what you're saying. However, if I include the id in the criteria part of the upsert, and leave it out of the update part, if the record doesn't exist, will the record be inserted with the "id" specified in the criteria, or will the id remain blank?

Comment: An upsert will always include BOTH the criteria and the update in the newly created document. So yes, your _id will be added.

Comment: @Remon
That is actually not true. When you run `db.stuff.update({_id: "foo"}, {bar: "baz"}, true, false)`, and that object did not exist, you'll get something like `{ "_id" : ObjectId("50a368dea3a163f3305d3cb4"), "bar" : "baz" }` in database. At least in version 2.2.1

Comment: @ghik True, in fact that's exactly what a save(..) operation does when a value for _id is set in the parameter. Which is exactly why you'd never actually have the upsert you're describing here since not having operators in your update clause is the only exception to what I mentioned above and that use case is fully covered by the more convenient save(...) method. Also note that that only works if _id is an ObjectId.

Comment: I filed a bug for this.  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8384  It's upsetting that the behaviour for a sharded cluster is different to non-sharded, as it's very difficult to test for this sort of discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to this question is that there is a bug in mongodb 2.0.  Check this jira issue:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3657